# Получение путей в папки автозапуска (Startup) из реестра

Tags: python, python-3.x, реестр, winreg, startup

Согласно [статье](http://www.infosecurity.ru/_gazeta/content/090904/art3.shtml) папки автозапуска (Startup) могут быть для всех пользователей и для текущего, плюс их расположение можно поменять через реестр, поэтому и нужно их пути получать из реестра

Возможные пути:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Common Startup`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Startup`

Нужно получить их **абсолютные пути** и путь к папке `SystemExplorerDisabled` (это папка для тех файлов, которые были убраны из автозапуска)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Путей больше, всего в реестре их 8 ([ссылка на список](https://safezone.cc/threads/sposoby-avtozapuska.1275/)):

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders, Common Startup
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders, Common AltStartup
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, Common Startup
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, Common AltStartup
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders, Startup
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders, AltStartup
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, Startup
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, AltStartup
```

Причем, те, что с **AltStartup** устаревшие и не используются больше: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/csidl

#### **UPD.**:

В предыдущей версии ответа было 2 пути и учитывались пути с `SystemExplorerDisabled`, что неправильно т.к. эту папку создает программа `SystemExplorer`, и я понял это после :)

#### Решение через модуль [winreg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) и `pathlib`:

- Описал в список все пути
- Сделал функцию, что по указанному пути и имени значения вернет путь
- Сделал функцию, что вернет список файлов по всем путям

#### Код:

##### [common.py](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fb22c268b29670dbbfe86afb2fcb254582614c4c/winreg__examples/common.py):

```
import os
import winreg

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Optional
from pathlib import Path
from winreg import QueryInfoKey, EnumValue, OpenKey, HKEYType


@dataclass
class Entry:
    name: str
    value: str
    type: int


def expand_registry_key(key: str) -> str:
    return {
        'HKCU': 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
        'HKLM': 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    }.get(key, key)


def get_key(path: str) -> Optional[HKEYType]:
    # Example:
    #     path = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    #     registry_key_name = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
    #     relative_path = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    registry_key_name, relative_path = path.split('\\', maxsplit=1)
    registry_key_name = expand_registry_key(registry_key_name)

    registry_key = getattr(winreg, registry_key_name)

    try:
        return OpenKey(registry_key, relative_path)
    except:
        return


def get_entries(path: str, expand_vars=True) -> List[Entry]:
    items = []

    key = get_key(path)
    if not key:
        return items

    _, number_of_values, _ = QueryInfoKey(key)
    for i in range(number_of_values):
        name, value, type_value = EnumValue(key, i)
        value = str(value)
        if expand_vars:
            value = os.path.expandvars(value)

        items.append(
            Entry(name, value, type_value)
        )

    return items


def get_entry(path: str, value: str, expand_vars=True) -> Optional[Entry]:
    for entry in get_entries(path, expand_vars):
        if entry.name == value:
            return entry


def get_entry_path(path: str, name: str) -> Optional[Path]:
    entry = get_entry(path, name)
    if not entry:
        return

    return Path(entry.value)
```

##### [get_startup_paths.py](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/44e232228bbad7455d4cc8982efc449870090963/winreg__examples/get_startup_paths.py)

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

from common import get_entry_path


PATHS = [
    (r'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders', 'Common Startup'),
    (r'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders', 'Common AltStartup'),
    (r'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders', 'Common Startup'),
    (r'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders', 'Common AltStartup'),

    (r'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders', 'Startup'),
    (r'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders', 'AltStartup'),
    (r'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders', 'Startup'),
    (r'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders', 'AltStartup'),
]


def get_path_files(path: Path, ignored_by_mask=('*.ini',)) -> List[Path]:
    items = []
    if path and path.exists():
        for file in path.iterdir():
            if not file.is_file() or any(fnmatch(file.name, mask) for mask in ignored_by_mask):
                continue

            items.append(file)

    return items


def get_all_files(ignored_by_mask=('*.ini',)) -> List[Path]:
    items = []

    for key_path, value in PATHS:
        path = get_entry_path(key_path, value)

        for file in get_path_files(path, ignored_by_mask):
            if file not in items:
                items.append(file)

    return items
```

##### Пример использования:

```
for key_path, value in PATHS:
    path = get_entry_path(key_path, value)
    print(fr'{key_path}\{value} = {path}')

    files = get_path_files(path)
    print(f'    Files ({len(files)}): {files}')

print()

all_files = get_all_files()
print(f'All files ({len(all_files)}): {all_files}')
```