# Получение списка команд на автозапуск из реестра Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, реестр, startup, winreg

*Продолжаю решать задачи получения программ из автозапуска, начавшуюся с [получения путей к папкам Startup из реестра](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1330310/201445) :)*

**Задача**: получить все программы из автозапуска в реестре

Ключи для примера:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Пример получения по ключу списка значений, в котором будут программы на автозапуск для текущего пользователя:

```
import winreg

from typing import Optional
from winreg import QueryInfoKey, EnumValue, OpenKey, HKEYType


def get_key(path: str) -> Optional[HKEYType]:
    # Example:
    #     path = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    #     registry_key_name = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
    #     relative_path = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    registry_key_name, relative_path = path.split('\\', maxsplit=1)
    registry_key = getattr(winreg, registry_key_name)

    try:
        return OpenKey(registry_key, relative_path)
    except:
        return


key = get_key(r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")

_, number_of_values, _ = QueryInfoKey(key)
for i in range(number_of_values):
    name, value, type_value = EnumValue(key, i)
    print(name, value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действия:

- Расширил список ключей (примеры взял из источников ниже)
- Для удобства работы с кодом:

  - Обернул в функцию
  - Значения храню в классе

Источники:

- https://www.windxp.com.ru/autrun.htm
- http://www.infosecurity.ru/_gazeta/content/090904/art3.shtml

[Решение:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/39a39db5562bf03e18dec8f9281e620cbdb96492/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L30)

```
import os
import winreg

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, List, Optional
from winreg import QueryInfoKey, EnumValue, OpenKey, HKEYType


def get_key(path: str) -> Optional[HKEYType]:
    # Example:
    #     path = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    #     registry_key_name = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
    #     relative_path = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    registry_key_name, relative_path = path.split('\\', maxsplit=1)
    registry_key = getattr(winreg, registry_key_name)

    try:
        return OpenKey(registry_key, relative_path)
    except:
        return


PATHS = [
    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",

    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce",

    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run",

    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce",

    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices",

    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce",

    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\Setup",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\Setup",

    r"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windows\load",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit",
    r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx",
]


@dataclass
class RegistryValue:
    name: str
    value: str
    type: int


def get_run_paths(expand_vars=True) -> Dict[str, List[RegistryValue]]:
    path_by_values = dict()

    for path in PATHS:
        if path not in path_by_values:
            path_by_values[path] = []

        key = get_key(path)
        if not key:
            continue

        _, number_of_values, _ = QueryInfoKey(key)
        for i in range(number_of_values):
            name, value, type_value = EnumValue(key, i)
            value = str(value)
            if expand_vars:
                value = os.path.expandvars(value)

            path_by_values[path].append(
                RegistryValue(name, value, type_value)
            )

    return path_by_values
```

Пример использования:

```
run_paths = get_run_paths()
for path, values in run_paths.items():
    print(path)

    for i, value in enumerate(values, 1):
        print(f'    {i}. {value.name}: {value.value}')

    print()
```

---

#### UPD 21.01.2022

Количество место для автозапусков огромное, поэтому опишу то, что было найдено с добавлением постоянных ссылок на скрипты из гитхаба.

Для удобства восприятия приведу таблицу на основе [этой статьи](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2762082&seqNum=2) (но скриптов было больше ([см. тут](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/15a8567ae2ece30f1fb49443c42f1e45edc2ee03/winreg__examples)), т.к. в статье не все места описаны, но, думаю, и скрипты не охватят все возможные места, т.к. например по Internet Explorer ничего не заполнял).

Пояснение по типу:

- **список** - список пар значений, это для тех разделов, у которых каждый параметр это отдельная простая сущность. Например, название параметра - название программы, а значение - путь
- **значение** - конкретное значение параметра раздела, представляющее интерес
- **сложная структура** - например, это сущность, имеющая собственный раздел (часто название раздела - GUID) с вложенными разделами и/или множеством параметров

| Путь | Тип |
| --- | --- |
| **Per-user ASEPs under HKCU\Software** |  |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L17) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L22) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L35) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Runonce](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L36) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunonceEx](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L37) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Load](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L51) | значение |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L52) | значение |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L54) | значение |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_active_setup_installed_components.py#L20) | [сложная структура](https://windowsnotes.ru/registry-2/active-setup/) |
|  |  |
| **Per-user ASEPs under HKCU\Software—64-bit only** |  |
| [HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L19) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L24) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_active_setup_installed_components.py#L21) | [сложная структура](https://windowsnotes.ru/registry-2/active-setup/) |
|  |  |
| **Per-user ASEPs under HKCU\Software intended to be controlled through Group Policy** |  |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L27) | список |
| [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Shell](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L69) | значение |
| [HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logon](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/15a8567ae2ece30f1fb49443c42f1e45edc2ee03/winreg__examples/get_group_policy_scripts.py#L14) | сложная структура |
| [HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logoff](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/15a8567ae2ece30f1fb49443c42f1e45edc2ee03/winreg__examples/get_group_policy_scripts.py#L14) | сложная структура |
|  |  |
| **Systemwide ASEPs in the registry** |  |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L18) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L23) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L31) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_active_setup_installed_components.py#L18) | [сложная структура](https://windowsnotes.ru/registry-2/active-setup/) |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L39) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Runonce](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L40) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunonceEx](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L41) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\IconServiceLib](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L49) | значение |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AlternateShells\AvailableShells](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L64) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AppSetup](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L56) | значение |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L58) | значение |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Taskman](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L60) | значение |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L62) | значение |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\VmApplet](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L63) | значение |
| [HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\AlternateShell](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L66) | значение |
| [HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Wds\rdpwd\StartupPrograms](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L44) | значение |
| [HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\InitialProgram](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L43) | значение |
|  |  |
| **Systemwide ASEPs in the registry, intended to be controlled through Group Policy** |  |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L28) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Shell](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L70) | значение |
| [HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/15a8567ae2ece30f1fb49443c42f1e45edc2ee03/winreg__examples/get_group_policy_scripts.py#L15) | сложная структура |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/15a8567ae2ece30f1fb49443c42f1e45edc2ee03/winreg__examples/get_group_policy_scripts.py#L12) | сложная структура |
|  |  |
| **Systemwide ASEPs in the registry—64-bit only** |  |
| [HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L20) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L25) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L33) | список |
| [HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_active_setup_installed_components.py#L19) | [сложная структура](https://windowsnotes.ru/registry-2/active-setup/) |
|  |  |
| **Systemwide ActiveSync ASEPs in the registry** |  |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L75) | [список](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43113279/5909792) |
| [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L76) | [список](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43113279/5909792) |
|  |  |
| **Systemwide ActiveSync ASEPs in the registry—64-bit only** |  |
| [HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L78) | [список](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43113279/5909792) |
| [HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/aa708d5d94222bfa219f2738adc56dde39dc5736/winreg__examples/get_run_paths.py#L79) | [список](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43113279/5909792) |

Comment: Всё равно списочек коротковат и неполон. Но главное - непонятна цель публикации. Ни вопрос, ни решение - какой-то блог по процессу создания решения получается...

Comment: @Akina, вы правы, список меньше чем мог, т.к. изначально делал для себя и не включал в список пути, что относятся к старым версиям windows и уже не поддерживаются. Расширил список, добавив следующие ключи: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windows\load`, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit`, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx`. Не нашел такого решения на стеке, поэтому добавил, посчитав, что это может быть полезно :) Спасибо за критику :)

Comment: Запусти AutoRuns. Включи отображение "пустых" разделов... найдётся ещё дофига всякого, что надо чекать, особенно всякие shell, logon/logoff и startup/shutdows... и задания планировщика. *посчитав, что это может быть полезно* - насчёт полезности как бы сомнений-то как раз нет. Правда, мне, как не использующему питон, трудно понять полезность в реализации именно в этом, не сильно (может, только пока?) популярном у админов средстве, но на PS/VBS такие инструменты точно есть (и их несложно применить из других ЯП, библиотека-то в системе с гарантией имеется).

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, посмотрю :)

Comment: @Akina, это заняло больше времени, чем ожидалось :D